# Online convex programming: Projection followed by normalization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have the following projected gradient descent online linear programming problem which has been well studied in 
www.cs.cmu.edu/~maz/publications/techconvex.pdf‎

$\mathbf{y}_{t+1}=\mathbf{w}_t - \eta \mathbf{l}_t $

$\mathbf{w}_{t+1}=\operatorname{argmin}_{\mathbf{w} \in \Omega}  \|\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{y}_{t+1}\|_2 $

where $\|.\|_2$ stands for $l_2$ norm, $\mathbf{l}_t$ is the (gradient of the cost function) cost occurred at round t and $\Omega$ is a given convex set where we hope our weights lay in.

Now I want to add a normalization step to this approach as follows:

$\mathbf{D}_{t+1} = \frac{\mathbf{w}_{t+1}}{\|\mathbf{w}_{t+1}\|_1}$

The question is: Is it now possible to prove any non trivial regret bound for this approach that is:

$R_T = \sum_{t=1}^T \langle \mathbf{l}_t,D_t \rangle - \min_\mathbf{D} \langle \mathbf{D},\mathbf{l}_t \rangle $

where $R_T$ is the regret of this algorithm.

Comment: You need to use mathjax for formatting. I made a few edits above that might help. The inner product is written using \langle \rangle as in $\langle x,y  \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot copper.hat. I spent about an hour to figure out how to use latex in stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, it takes a while to get used to.

Comment: Are you sure $I_t$ is the cost occured? It seems like it should be the gradient of the cost function at $w_t$.

Comment: it is the gradient of the cost function. My bad. Since it is linear, it will end up being a cost vector.

Answer (score 0):

OK. 3 years later. It turns out that under certain conditions it is in fact possible to prove a regret bound for the above mentioned online convex programming. See here for more details:

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5512-a-boosting-framework-on-grounds-of-online-learning